# Jest TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs, babeljs

Below settings for my package.json

If I run from command line `npm test` all jest test cases are executed properly.
In case I use directly the command `jest` from command line I receive this error:

> Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
>
>   at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
>   at Object.relative (path.js:538:5)
> ```

This happens on any test files.

Any idea what could be wrong and how to fix it?

```
 "scripts": {
        "test": "standard && jest",
        "format": "standard --fix",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.dev.js",
        "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js"
    },
```

Comment: I have the same problem, nothings helped so far.

Comment: Since the project configuration is such a common failure point for builds involving jest (and other node/JS/NPM/yarn libraries) including all of your package.json is as important as including code. The answers below reflect this; they're mostly just telling you to clean and reinstall, which only helps if your config was basically working in the first place, and it probably is the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I solved this issue using:

- npm uninstall -g jest
- npm install -g jest
- npm cache clean
- npm install

Answer (score 19):

I am not entirely sure what the problem here is, but I was facing the same issue and what worked for me was updating the Jest version. I was using 20 but I switched to 21 and now it magically works again.

Update version in `package.json` and then run `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Had the same issue. Upgrading to 21 fixed it. Even got a progress bar for the tests :)

Answer (score 15):

In my case i had to update jest to version 21.x (from 20.x).

Try running `npm install jest@latest --save-dev`.

Answer (score 7):

For me, it was the jest-cli package bumping to 21.x. So `npm update jest-cli --save-dev`

Answer (score 2):

For me I had to downgrade. Version 21.x worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue using:

remove `node_modules`
remove `package-lock.json`

remove dev dependence from `package.json` of jest `npm remove jest --save-dev.`

`npm cache clean`

then run command `npm install`

then install `npm install jest@latest --save-dev`

this works for me

Answer (score 1):

`npm install react-dev-utils@10.1.0`

Installing this version of `react-dev-utils` helped, when sometimes the commands in the accepted answers didn't.

Good luck y'all!