# Jest fails on anythings: path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have the same problem as [this "duplicate" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220674/jest-typeerror-path-must-be-a-string-received-undefined). I made an empty project and installed only jest. Then I created one sample test file. When I run jest, it gives an error:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/test.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined

  at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
  at Object.relative (path.js:1254:5)
```

I have the latest version of npm, and the jest version is 21.2.1. Mac.
Any ideas what might be causing it?

EDIT: version 20.0.4 works just fine, so I go with it for now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jest TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220674/jest-typeerror-path-must-be-a-string-received-undefined)

Comment: downgrading to 20.0.4 didn't work for me :(

Comment: Sorry to hear it... did you try it on an empty project? If it works, then deleting package-lock and node_modules and then doing npm install again could help.